# Can't connect to the global peer-to-peer network

Tags: windows, remote-assistance

When I use the [Remote Assistance](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4026516/windows-use-remote-assistance-to-let-someone-fix-your-pc) from my Windows, I cannot follow the "Easy Connect" route. I am able to invite others by sending them the invitation file, but it would be cool if I only need to tell them the password. The "Easy Connect" function is expected to work like in [this guide](https://www.guidingtech.com/5834/windows-7-remote-assistance-easy-connect/). When I follow that guide, I get stuck after clicking "Use Easy Connect": instead of getting the password, I got

[image: Easy Connect is not available]

I tried Windows 10 and Windows 8.1 and neither works, so I think it is independent of my OS version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched online and I found [this forum post](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-networking/remote-assistance-easy-connect-cant-connect-to/fcb92fed-3d05-400d-bb15-690adcced3d1). "TrueRock2" replied on February 7, 2014:

> The "Easy Connect" feature of "Windows Remote Assistance" requires IPv6…
>
> Microsoft disabled the IPv6 tunneling server that supported "Easy Connect" in the middle of 2013 and this disabled the functionality of "Easy Connect".  I assume the reason Microsoft did this is because it looks like the network-world is finally getting ready to start using IPv6.  Microsoft and many other IT corporations seem to be "clearing the decks" and preparing for this event.  Just a guess on my part.

I verified with two of my friends, one without IPv6 (like me), the other with IPv6 (from Comcast). Only the latter was able to get the Easy Connect password, so I think that's it. The network-world turns out *not yet* ready to start using IPv6, Microsoft…

Comment: So is there a way to get IPv6 onto the computer, or is that entirely hardware?

Comment: @MasterHD First of all, your ISP (Internet Service Provider) need to support IPv6; in my region Verizon doesn't, for example. Then you need to make sure your router supports IPv6 (most new ones do). I have also heard of the idea "Tunneling IPv6 through IPv4 network" (looks like Microsoft used to do this for you), but I don't know much about that.

Comment: Can you update this answer for circa 2021?

Comment: @Burt_Harris I believe this answer is still valid as it is. Just tested in Windows 10, OS Build 19042.1165, IPv6 is still required for Easy Connect to work